# ? E: audit error in android in firebase db

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I trying to read data and after pressing button nothing happened. When i opened LogCat i saw this error:

> type=1400 audit(506975.539:15): avc: denied { read write } for pid=5920 comm="print" name=

But in firebase rules i  have this code:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
    }
  }
```

When i added path in rules:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "User" : {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

I have this error:

```
E/audit: type=1400 msg=audit(1678006800.443:43969): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=840 comm="smdexe" path="/data/.socket_stream" scontext=u:r:smdexe:s0 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0

? E/audit:  SEPF_SM-J200H_5.1.1_0018

? E/audit: type=1300 msg=audit(1678006800.443:43969): arch=40000028 syscall=283 per=800000 success=no exit=-13 a0=4 a1=b63efcfc a2=6e a3=b6f99910 items=0 ppid=1 pid=840 auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 ses=4294967295 tty=(none) comm="smdexe" exe="/system/bin/smdexe" subj=u:r:smdexe:s0 key=(null)
? E/audit: type=1320 msg=audit(1678006800.443:43969):
```

Comment: It looks like your code is trying to read something else than `/User`, which is not allowed by the second rules you show. Without seeing the [minimal code that triggers the error message](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to say more.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.